# sequence, such that sum of any combinations in the sequence does not equal another

Tags: sequences-and-series, integer-sequences, infinite-sequences, spectral-sequences

Hi, 
   Is there any known sequence such that the sum of a combination of one subsequence never equals another subsequence sum. The subsequences should have elements only from the parent sequence.

Thanks
Sundi

Comment: The sequence $.1, .01, .001, .0001,\ldots$ will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

got it, thanks, just a gp series would do. 1,2,4,8,16...

Answer (score 1):

Other sequences that immediately come to mind are vector-like expressions
$$(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...), (0, 1, 0, 0, 0, ...) , (0, 0, 1, 0, 0, ...), ...$$
(or matrices or tensors) or the sequence $(a_n)$ of approximations of transcendentals like Liouville's number $$a_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{k!}$$
or just terminating rationals with different points of termination behind the decimal point $$0.1, 0.11, 0.111, ...$$
or before$$1, 10, 100, ... $$

But that's already very close to the first answer.